# JSON returned from Memcache is invalid

Tags: 7, caching

I have `Drupal 7` site. I am using `Memcache` for caching.

This is how I am storing the JSON into it

```
    //creating an object of Memcache
    $cache = new Memcache();
    $cache ->addServer('localhost', 11211);
    //adding a key
    $cacheKey = 'mobile';
    //delete old cache
    $cache ->delete($cacheKey);
    //refresh cache
    $cache ->set($cacheKey, serialize($jsonData));
```

No issue till here. But when fetching the JSON from this cache.

**returned JSON fails to validate**

I am using `http://jsonlint.com/` to validate my JSON.

Please note the however the JSON has correct data but issue is validation.

```
$Records = $cache->get($cacheKey);

echo '<pre>';
print_r(Records);
exit();
```

**JSON**

```
{
"defaults": [{
    "nid": "213",
    "public_url": "http:\/\/www.mywebsite.com",
    "HTMLStr": "layout and user interface.\
    r\ n\ t
    http: \ /\/mywebsite.com<\/a><\/p>\r\n"
}]
```

}

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** really related to Drupal since you are not using the Drupal Memcache module API.

But based on your example. Here is my test code.

```
  // Creating an object of Memcache
  $cache = new Memcache();
  $cache->addServer('localhost', 11211);
  // Adding a key.
  $cacheKey = 'mobile';
  // Delete old cache.
  $cache ->delete($cacheKey);
  // Create a temp json data.
  $jsonData = "{
    'glossary': {
        'title': 'example glossary',
                'GlossDiv': {
            'title': 'S',
                        'GlossList': {
                'GlossEntry': {
                    'ID': 'SGML',
                                        'SortAs': 'SGML',
                                        'GlossTerm': 'Standard Generalized Markup Language',
                                        'Acronym': 'SGML',
                                        'Abbrev': 'ISO 8879:1986',
                                        'GlossDef': {
                        'para': 'A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.',
                                                'GlossSeeAlso': ['GML', 'XML']
                      },
                                        'GlossSee': 'markup'
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }";
  // Set the cache.
  $cache ->set($cacheKey, serialize($jsonData));
  // Fetch the cache.
  $Records = $cache->get($cacheKey);

  // Dump the cache.
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($Records);
  echo '</pre>';
```

and here is the result

```
s:881:"{
    'glossary': {
        'title': 'example glossary',
                'GlossDiv': {
            'title': 'S',
                        'GlossList': {
                'GlossEntry': {
                    'ID': 'SGML',
                                        'SortAs': 'SGML',
                                        'GlossTerm': 'Standard Generalized Markup Language',
                                        'Acronym': 'SGML',
                                        'Abbrev': 'ISO 8879:1986',
                                        'GlossDef': {
                        'para': 'A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.',
                                                'GlossSeeAlso': ['GML', 'XML']
                      },
                                        'GlossSee': 'markup'
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }";
```

with `$Records = unserialize($cache->get($cacheKey));` here is the result.

```
{
    'glossary': {
        'title': 'example glossary',
                'GlossDiv': {
            'title': 'S',
                        'GlossList': {
                'GlossEntry': {
                    'ID': 'SGML',
                                        'SortAs': 'SGML',
                                        'GlossTerm': 'Standard Generalized Markup Language',
                                        'Acronym': 'SGML',
                                        'Abbrev': 'ISO 8879:1986',
                                        'GlossDef': {
                        'para': 'A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.',
                                                'GlossSeeAlso': ['GML', 'XML']
                      },
                                        'GlossSee': 'markup'
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

The only reason why you are not able to see the result is because of this.

```
print_r(Records);
```

which is it should be

```
print_r($Records);
```

`Record` is a variable and therefore it must have a dollar sign before it.

**Test your connection to Memcache**

```
  $cache = new Memcache();
  $cache->addServer('localhost', 11211);
  $stats = @$cache->getExtendedStats();
  $available = (bool) $stats["localhost:11211"];
  var_dump($available);
```

If the result is `true` then you are connected to Memcache if `false` then you are not connected.

**UPDATE 1:**

I tested with your json.

```
  $arr = array(
    "nid" => "213",
    "public_url" => "http:\/\/www.mywebsite.com",
    "HTMLStr" => "layout and user interface.\ r\ n\ t http: \ /\/mywebsite.com<\/a><\/p>\r\n",
  );
  $jsonData = json_encode($arr, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_APOS);
```

and here is the result

```
s:157:"{"nid":"213","public_url":"http:\\\/\\\/www.mywebsite.com","HTMLStr":"layout and user interface.\\ r\\ n\\ t http: \\ \/\\\/mywebsite.com<\\\/a><\\\/p>\r\n"}";
```

Comment: `print_r(Records)` is my typo mistake, here. I am using `print_r($Records)` only

Comment: The make sure that your Memcache server is running and it is on 11211 port.

Comment: Please note I have HTML string in my values

Comment: Would be good if you can post your `$jsonData`.

Comment: JSON added below my question

Comment: Please see my update. Test your connectivity.

Comment: Yes. It returned true

Comment: Its working fine in my end.

Comment: Wondering how did you assign the json on `$jsonData` variable?

Comment: Wait, is `print_r` returning nothing?

Comment: ` $jsonData = json_encode($arr, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_APOS);`

Comment: See my update. Still working fine.

Comment: you desire an UPvote :D

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to deserialize the data with

> [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

like:

```
$Records = unserialize($cache->get($cacheKey));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($Records);
exit();
```

Comment: Checked with it. Still the same issue